# custom Facebook logout button not worked in IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, logout

I am new to IOS and I created a Facebook custom login and logout buttons for my app using Facebook SDK. Login button works as I expected, but when I clicked my logout button, it gives the login page as I redirected to it. Then, when I try to login again, it doesn't show the Facebook login UI. But when I logged out my Facebook app and try to login to my app, the login UI works well. Here is my logout button.

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {

    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    NSLog(@"log out");
    LoginUIViewController *loginController1= [[LoginUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginUIViewController" bundle:nil];
      [self presentViewController:loginController1 animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Do I need to implement a logout button in my view controller or does FB SDK provides the logout facility it self?

**@ Vinod Jat,,**
    **I made following changes in my appDelegate..**

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.viewController = [[SplashViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        // Whenever a person opens the app, check for a cached session
        if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {

            // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
            [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                               allowLoginUI:NO
                                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
    [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
        }

      return YES;

    }

    //This method will handle ALL the session state changes in the app
    - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
    { 
        // If the session was opened successfully
        if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
            NSLog(@"Session opened");

            return;
        }
        if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
            // If the session is closed
            NSLog(@"Session closed");

        }
    .........
    }


 **In my loginUIViewController I have added following method..**

- (IBAction)FbloginButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"inside login button");

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:
         ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"inside login button2");

             // Retrieve the app delegate
             TNLAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
             // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
            [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
              NSLog(@"inside login button3");
         }];
  //redirect to now playing page
    NowPlayingViewController *nowPlaying= [[NowPlayingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NowPlayingViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:nowPlaying animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Have you heared about SSO ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SSO.How can I use it for my problem? Do you have any codes?

Comment: can you show the code you are using for login ?

Comment: I edited my question with my code..